# concise way to match filenames that end in certain extension in Python?

Tags: python, regex, filesystems, glob

What's the canonical way to handle to retrieve all files in a directory that end in a particular extension, e.g. "All files that end in `.ext` or `.ext2` in a case insensitive way?"  One way is using `os.listdir` and `re` module:

```
import re
files = os.listdir(mydir)
# match in case-insensitive way all files that end in '.ext' or '.ext2'
p = re.compile(".ext(2)?$", re.IGNORECASE)
matching_files = [os.path.join(mydir, f) for f in files if p.search(x) is not None]
```

Is there a preferred way to do this more concisely with `glob` or `fnmatch`? The annoyance with `listdir` is that one has to handle the path all the time, by prepending with `os.path.join` the directory to the basename of each file it returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob("testdir/*")
['testdir/a.txt', 'testdir/b.txt', 'testdir/d.ext', 'testdir/c.ExT2']
>>> [f for f in glob.glob("testdir/*") if f.lower().endswith((".ext", ".ext2"))]
['testdir/d.ext', 'testdir/c.ExT2']
```